# ImageButton control with Google TV android application development

Tags: android, android-layout, google-tv

My application is working successfully in **Android 2.x to 4.1.x**

In Google TV emulator i am running my existing application.

Google TV is not support touch input, So user must use navigation flow like **move left, move right, move top and move bottom.**

But this control can not point on ImageButton control.

How can reach my pointer for operate ImageButton.?

**XML Layout** :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headingTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Kit - Device Registration"
        android:textSize="75sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/kitDetailsRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headingTextView"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/WebURLTextView"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Web Url:"
            android:textSize="50dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/WebURLEditText"
            style="@style/EditTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="700dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/WebURLTextView"
            android:hint="Enter Web Url"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/KitNoTextView"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/WebURLTextView"
            android:layout_below="@id/WebURLEditText"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="KIT No:"
            android:textSize="50dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/KitNoEditText"
            style="@style/EditTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="700dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/WebURLTextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/KitNoTextView"
            android:hint="Enter KIT No"
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/UniqueIdTextView"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/WebURLTextView"
            android:layout_below="@id/KitNoEditText"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Unique Id:"
            android:textSize="50dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/UniqueIdEditText"
            android:layout_width="700dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/KitNoTextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/UniqueIdTextView"
            android:editable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ih_comBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/KitNoTextView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/WebURLEditText"
            android:text="@string/lbl_host_name"
            android:textSize="35sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/topSettingsIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/streak_settings" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/kitControlRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/quitBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/quit_button" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/verifyBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/quitBtn"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/quitBtn"
            android:background="@drawable/register_button" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/clearBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/quitBtn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/quitBtn"
            android:background="@drawable/clear_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java File Code :**

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
//Other Imports

    public class <classs Name> extends Activity {
        EditText webUrlEditTextObj;
        EditText uniqueIdEditTextObj;
        /**
         * Refers to Register image button
         */
        private ImageButton registerBtnObj;
        /**
         * Refers to Quit image button
         */
        private ImageButton quitBtnObj;
        /**
         * Refers to Clear image button
         */
        private ImageButton clearBtnObj;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            setContentView(R.layout.<XML file Name>);

            //...
            registerBtnObj = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.verifyBtn);
            quitBtnObj = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.quitBtn);
            clearBtnObj = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.clearBtn);

            verifyBtnObj.setOnClickListener(verifyListener);
            quitBtnObj.setOnClickListener(quitListener);
            clearBtnObj.setOnClickListener(clearListener);

            //...
        }

    /**
     * Listener for Register button click.
     */
    private OnClickListener verifyListener = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            /**
             * Block of code
             */
        }
    };

    /**
     * Listener for Quit button click.
     */
    private OnClickListener quitListener = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            /**
             * Block of code
             */
        }
    };

    /**
     * Listener for Clear button click.
     */
    private OnClickListener clearListener = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            /**
             * Block of code
             */
        }
    };  
}
```

Comment: post some code here......

Comment: I put XML file and Java code above.

Comment: In android "ImageButton"has default propertie android:focusable="true" but I seen that you might be check that your background selector for "ImageButton" should set under the [ state_focused="true"]. if you have "ImageView" then you need to set the properties [ android:focusable="true" ]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your ImageButtons are marked as focusable.  You'll also want to make sure you set the nextFocus* related attributes as well.  The following is from my project, Serenity for Android which uses ImageButtons on the OSD when playing a video.

```
   <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/osd_rewind_control"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:nextFocusRight="@+id/mediacontroller_play_pause"
        android:nextFocusUp="@+id/mediacontroller_seekbar"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        style="@android:style/MediaButton.Rew"
        android:src="@drawable/skipback_selector"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

Again make sure you set the android:focusable to true.  All source code for my app is available to look at as well.

https://github.com/NineWorlds/serenity-android/blob/master/serenity-app/res/layout-large/serenity_media_controller.xml